# How can I use ord2 function

Tags: octave

I'm using Octave right now, but earlier I had used MatLab. In MatLab there is a function ord2 and according to this document (http://www.obihiro.ac.jp/~suzukim/masuda/octave/html3/octave_159.html/) it should also exist in Octave. Could anyone help me with this issue, since I'm new in Octave. How can I import or in other way use 'ord2' function (second-ordered system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you mention is for Octave 3.0 which is a very very old version. All of Control functions, together with Finance and Quaternion, were removed from core Octave with release 3.2. If you see the news for Octave 3.2 (if you have a very recent version, this may be in one of the old news file:

> ** The Control, Finance and Quaternion functions have been removed.
>
> These functions are now available as separate packages from
>
> ```
>  http://octave.sourceforge.net/packages.html
> ```
>
> and can be reinstalled using the Octave package manager (see
>      the pkg function).

As it is mentioned, you can download the packages from Octave Forge website but depending on your operating system, you may be better off use your package manager.

Finally, the `ord2` function does not actually exist in the control package and I'm even unsure that the version you are referring to in Octave 3.0 was even Matlab compatible. However, you can still see its [source online](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/4a423a042971/scripts/control/system/ord2.m) right before it was removed.